# How to setup relation between three entites with classes

Tags: mysql, database, entity-relationship, data-modeling

I have four classes

1. User
2. profiles
3. Activity
4. Workbook

---

1. user can have many profiles based on per year. Every year diff profile
2. `User profile`  will  have `many to many` with `Activities`

---

so there will be `profile_activities` table with `profile_id` and `activity_id`

Now User will do 1 workbook per activity per profile

so i am confused how to map in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've revised my suggestion in light of your comment.

Perhaps could have an UserActivity class which has an Activity property and a Workbook property.

Then you can have a User class with a property that is a list of Profile classes, and the Profile class will have a property that is a list of UserActivity classes.

This satisfies your object model.

So the UserActivity table will have a foreign key to a row in the Profile table (which will be its parent ID), and foreign keys to the Activity and Workbook tables.

Your Profile table has a foreign key to a row in the User table which is its parentID.

Comment: I am using ORM , so how can i map the relationship table primary key because its not defined